# UICollectionView Dynamic Cell Height as per the content | Pinterest Layouts

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift5, pinterest, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to do a layout as Pinterest uses for their image gallery. But the issue is that I'm returning the image height to the size of the cells and when the images have different heights, it leaves spaces in the cells.

I have walked through lots of articles, but I have not found a simple solution. Is there any simple way we can do this?

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFFaM.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var collectionVIew: UICollectionView!
    var imgData = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p3"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p4"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p5"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p6"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p7"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p8"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p3"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p4"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p5"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p6"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p7"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p8"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p3"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p4"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p5"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p6"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p7"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p8"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p3"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p4"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p5"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p6"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p7"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "p8")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
        let img = imgData[indexPath.item]
        // 335 is the width of my cell image
        return CGSize(width: width/2-15, height: (img.size.height / 335) * width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.imgView.image = imgData[indexPath.row];
        cell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This might not be a direct answer to your question, but here's a great resource for you to learn to do just that: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjCzoWJruPeAhVFJhoKHWb4CqwQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest&usg=AOvVaw3OxQZGpeMX3VYBT1wVfEKr

Comment: Yes i see this article but the trick they use is too complex for me is there is another way we can achieved this thing then please tell me ?

Comment: @YogeshPatel - *"the trick they use"* is much better phrased as **the code they wrote**. That article is a complete walk-through tutorial answering your question -- **Like Pinterest in Swift**. If you really want to do a Pinterest style layout, you can't find much of a better resource than that article. https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: There is no easy way out. You will have to implement your own custom UICollectionViewLayout. Create your own custom layout. Set the attributes and assign that layout to your Collection View.

Comment: Yes you suggest this article is best but can we achieved this in less code and simple solution .? like calculate the y position and height of the 1 image that the position of height is the y of 3 image .?

Comment: https://github.com/MagicLab-team/PinterestLayout this will help you

Comment: @YogeshPatel have you got the solution? I tried 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest


this is working but It is static Way. If I download image from server then this layout is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have mentioned can be achieved using flow layout — a layout class provided by UIKit.

This is what you are looking for:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

I hope you can put some effort into reading this very simple post and follow each step carefully.

Comment: Thanks For Your Response, can we do same thing in less code with simple solution .? with out third party library

Comment: @Satish Flow layout will not be sufficient in this case. A custom layout will be needed.

Comment: NO, you should put some effort into it, why someone will provide you the cooked code. Go somewhere you can find a freelancer, and pay some amount to him for this work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fit non-square images into a square hole. When we do this something has to be given. In this case, I would recommend you make each of your cells a fixed height and set an aspect fill content mode on them so they fill the cell's frame completely. The downside is that some of the larger images will have part of them cut off. The other option is to use the aspect fit content mode which will scale the image to fit without losing a part of the image. This would leave you with the cell spacing again.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
    return CGSize(width: width/2-15, height: 100) // fixed height
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgView.image = imgData[indexPath.row];
    cell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill // Set the scale mode to aspect fill
    return cell
}
```

Alternatively, you can check out some open source libraries that might implement this for you. This one looks promising https://github.com/abdullahselek/ASCollectionView

You can check out a larger list of collection view open-source libraries here https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#collection-view

If you want the cells to have different heights you need to calculate the correct height based on the aspect ratio of the image and the width that is fixed. You calculate the aspect ratio in this case by the height/width when our width is fixed and our height is dynamic. Then multiply that by the width of the cell of the image to get our dynamic cell height.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width / 2 - 15;
    let img = imgData[indexPath.item]
    return CGSize(width: width, height: (img.size.height / img.size.width) * width)
}
```

You should set your content mode to aspect fit in this case.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imgView.image = imgData[indexPath.row];
    cell.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // Set the scale mode to aspect fit
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Response, with your solution if i fixed the height then the output is not like Pinterest it like gallery

Comment: Thanks For Library but can we do this thing without library .?

Comment: Of course you can do it without a library. Libraries just make things easier for us. I have added another section that should help. @YogeshPatel

Comment: Hello (img.size.height / image.size.width) * width .  img i got and devided by which image ??

Comment: it's not working some extra space are there in cell image

Comment: @YogeshPatel you can try setting it to scaleAspectFill and that should get rid of the space. Beyond that you will have to update your question with more things you are trying otherwise we can't help more.

Comment: i'm trying all image content mode but it not give me perfect solution wait i'm updating my question

Comment: Please check i just update question and please see the screen short and i just add your code and add background of cell okay